# How to shorten a string that is a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, string

I have a string as: `char** s`. Like this:

```
void cad_rem(char **s, int p){

}
```

where `s`is the string I need to remove one character in the `<p>` position.
If `p` is the last  character of the string-*just an example-* and I just make a:

**Update**

```
void cad_rem(char **s, int p){
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    if(!(p > len)){
        memmove(s + p, s + p + 1, len - p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Move every char to the right of <p> one step left. For example with memmove.

Comment: @folkol Hi ! Could you give me a sample ? I'm reading about `memmove` but I'm not sure about how to use this in my case.

Comment: No, you don't have a string that's a `char**`. You may have a `char**` pointer that points to a `char*` pointer that points to a string. `char* aux = s;` is invalid; you can't assign a `char**` value to a `char*` object.

Comment: @KeithThompson So How could i access the string that is pointed by the pointers ? How may I edit its content.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro: If `s` is of type `char**` (as it is in your example), then `*s` is of type `char*`, and may point to a string. How to edit the string depends on just what you want to do. For example, `(*s)[0] = 'x';` sets the first character of the string to `'x'`, and `strlen(*s)` gives you the length of the string.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you ! Actually, according to the debugger. `**s` returns me the first character of the string. Is that correct?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro: Yes. `s` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-`char`, `*s` is a pointer-to-`char`, and `**s` is a `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, `char **` is a pointer to a `char *`, not itself a string, so you'll have to dereference it. However, your function might just as well deal with a `char *` directly.

Something like this should work:

```
void cad_rem(char *s, size_t p)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    if (p >= len) {
        /* put code here to error out and return */
    }
```

To move the remaining characters, use `memmove`. From [the `memmove` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html):

> ```
> void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
> ```
>
> [...] The `memmove()` function copies `n` bytes from memory area `src` to memory area `dest`.

This could also be adapted easily to remove more than one character.

```
    memmove(s + p, s + p + 1, len - p);
}
```

This moves the remaining bytes of the string (including the terminator) from `s + p + 1` (i.e. starting after the character to be removed) to `s + p` (i.e. starting where that character used to be).

(`len - p` is the same as `len - p - 1 + 1`, which is the characters one character after the character at position `p`, plus one more for the trailing string terminator.)

If you know the size of your string, you can avoid the `strlen` call, in which case removing the last character is a matter of overwriting it with `'\0'`.

As for your suggested use of `realloc`, keep in mind C strings are typically terminated with a `\0` byte. If you're dealing with ordinary C strings (and based on your use of `strlen` you certainly seem to be), you'll need to make sure there's still a `\0` at the end of the string – and then, `realloc` isn't even necessary.

Comment: Thank you, sir ! Worked like a charm ! Could you explain some things to me ?  
in `memmove(s + p, s + p + 1, len - p);`.   

`s+p` = This is the position of the string the function will start working?    

`s+p+1` = What is this exactly ?

Comment: `s + p` is the destination, `s + p + 1` the source. In this case, it moves the remaining characters one character to the left – see also my updated answer. (`s + p` is a pointer to the `p`th character in the string, the one you want to remove; `s + p + 1` is a pointer to the character after that.)

Comment: I updated my question with the currently code. Nothing changes dude.. The value pointed by the pointer that S points to still the same.

Comment: You're still using a `char **` when a `char *` is likely what you want. That said, if for some reason you *have* to accept a `char **`, dereference it when you use it in the function.

Comment: Worked perfect dude. I was having some trouble to understand this `pointer-to-pointer` and was passing a wrong pointer as parameter. Now I got it. Really thanks for your help sir !